# What is a good way to implement an object pool?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I have a third party class, lets call it `Analyser`. This class is really good at analysing, but is expensive (seconds) to instantiate and does not support multi-threading.

My application needs to serve requests that involve calling `Analyser`. These requests will occur concurrently.

I think I need to create a generic class, something like

```
public class Pool<T>
{
    public Pool(Func<T> instantiator, int size)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task<TResult> Invoke<TResult>(
            Func<T, TResult> target,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // await the first available T,
        // lock the T,
        // invoke the target, return the result
        // release the lock
    }
}
```

This class will generically encapsulate the pooling functionality.

My question is, what is the right way to implement this class. Does it already exist with a different name? Should I use `TPL.DataFlow`? Should I be hand rolling it?

**Good** is defined as reliably thread-safe, the easier to maintain the better.

---

If a generic `Pool` is the wrong approach to the problem, please suggest a correct alternative.

---

The `Pool` class would be used something like this.

```
private readonly Pool<Analyser> pool = new Pool<Analyser>(
        () => new Analyser(a, b, c),
        100);

public async Task<string> ProcessRequest(
        string raw,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await this.pool.Invoke(
        analyser => analyser.Analyse(raw),
        cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: "await the first available T" concerns me - that sounds like an easy way to get a deadlock, if they are all in use, and all somehow requesting an *additional* T which will never be available (because everyone who owns a T is waiting for *moar Tz*)

Comment: @MarcGravell, If a "re-entrant" `target` delegate was passed to `Invoke` that would be a definite problem.

Comment: TPL.DataFlow (AFAIK) covers another kind of problems... where you have a "streaming-like" flow (e.g. Analyser passing the result to PostProcesser, then to Aggregator to combine them...)
Just for curiosity, why have you thought at DataFlow?

Comment: Also, can you add an example of how do you think your client code (the user of Pool) would look like? Or what you would like it to look like?

Comment: @LorenzoDematté because it handles concurrent activity very effectively out the box but, like you say, I don't see how to get the result back.

Comment: Another question: if a target requests another T in its body, would it be OK to pass back the same T it has already acquired, or would you need an entirely new T? (that *should* solve the deadlok issue @MarcGravell mentioned)

Comment: @LorenzoDematté It would probably be better to handle that edge case by throwing an exception. It makes me think, there must be a better way, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: How difficult would it be creating a thread-safe analyzer? That way you could enjoy the OOTB concurrency you get with `TPL Dataflow`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, very difficult and expensive, but I agree in principle that would be better.

Comment: IMO, a pool would suggest that you have X avaliable resources which you manage. This isn't the case here if i understand correctly. You have obe resource and you need to manage a queue of requests.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, no I intend to instantiate many, as defined by `size`, they are just expensive to instantiate. Doing so "on-the-fly" makes processing too slow. (I suspect this is due to hashing algorithm used by the third parties license check.)

Comment: So the pool needs to be of fixed size and should block in case someone requests the N + 1 analyzer where you have N analyzers?

Answer (score 4):

I think building a generic Pool would be a quite complex task, and therefore I'll have a lot of fun with it :-)

NOTE: the most important thing that differs in my vision from yours is that I don't want the pool the handle the threading concerns related the objects it manages. The pool has some thread-safety related code, but only for managing it's own state (the list of instances). 
Thread starting, stopping/ and/or cancelling are a concern for the client of the pool and for the constructed objects, not for the pool itself.

I would begin with:

1. A disposable wrapper for the objects to be maintained by the pool, that will return the object to the pool when disposed
2. A pool that construct or re-use available instances and wrap them before returning instances to the client.

A super simplified implementation:

```
class PoolItem<T> : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Disposed;


    public PoolItem(T wrapped)
    {
        WrappedObject = wrapped;
    }


    public T WrappedObject { get; private set; }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now the pool:

```
class Pool<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly object m_SyncRoot = new object();

    private readonly Func<T> m_FactoryMethod;
    private List<T> m_PoolItems = new List<T>();


    public Pool(Func<T> factoryMethod)
    {
        m_FactoryMethod = factoryMethod;
    }


    public PoolItem<T> Get()
    {
        T target = null;

        lock (m_SyncRoot)
        {
            if (m_PoolItems.Count > 0)
            {
                target = m_PoolItems[0];
                m_PoolItems.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        if (target == null)
            target = m_FactoryMethod();

        var wrapper = new PoolItem<T>(target);
        wrapper.Disposed += wrapper_Disposed;

        return wrapper;
    }


    void wrapper_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wrapper = sender as PoolItem<T>;

        lock (m_SyncRoot)
        {
            m_PoolItems.Add(wrapper.WrappedObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class ExpensiveConstructionObject
{
    public ExpensiveConstructionObject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing the expensive constructor...");
    }

    public void Do(string stuff)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing: " + stuff);
    }
}

    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool = new Pool<ExpensiveConstructionObject>(() => new ExpensiveConstructionObject());

        var t1 = pool.Get();
        t1.WrappedObject.Do("task 1");

        using (var t2 = pool.Get())
            t2.WrappedObject.Do("task 2");

        using (var t3 = pool.Get())
            t3.WrappedObject.Do("task 3");

        t1.Dispose();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Next steps would be:

1. classic pool features like: initial size, max size
2. dynamic proxing, allowing the Pool::Get return type to be T, not PoolItem
3. maintaing the list of wrappers, to dispose them if the caller does not when Pool gets disposed itself

Answer (score 3):

IIUC what you're trying to achieve is a generic object pool where when you don't have a resource to use, you wait asynchronously until you do.

The simplest solution would be to use a `TPL Dataflow`'s `BufferBlock` to both hold the items and to await on when it's empty. In your API you get a delegate and run it, but I would recommend returning the actual item from the pool and let the use decide what to do with it:

```
public class ObjectPool<TItem>
{
    private readonly BufferBlock<TItem> _bufferBlock;
    private readonly int _maxSize;
    private readonly Func<TItem> _creator;
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
    private readonly object _lock;
    private int _currentSize;

    public ObjectPool(int maxSize, Func<TItem> creator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _lock = new object();
        _maxSize = maxSize;
        _currentSize = 1;
        _creator = creator;
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        _bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<TItem>(new DataflowBlockOptions{CancellationToken = cancellationToken});
    }

    public void Push(TItem item)
    {
        if (!_bufferBlock.Post(item) || _bufferBlock.Count > _maxSize)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public Task<TItem> PopAsync()
    {
        TItem item;
        if (_bufferBlock.TryReceive(out item))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(item);
        }
        if (_currentSize < _maxSize)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_currentSize < _maxSize)
                {
                    _currentSize++;
                    _bufferBlock.Post(_creator());
                }
            }
        }

        return _bufferBlock.ReceiveAsync();
    }
}
```

**Explanations:**

- I use a lock to make sure you only create new item one at a time, this could be easily replaced with an `AsyncLock` if it takes a long time.
- I use [Double Check Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) to optimize for the common case where all the items are already created.
- `PopAsync` returns a `Task` but isn't an async method, so it completes synchronously as long as there's an item to return. It only waits when the pool is empty and the limit has been reached.

You can add a method that returns an `IDisposable` so you can just put it in a using `scope` without worry:

```
public async Task<Disposable> GetDisposableAsync()
{
    return new Disposable(this, await PopAsync());
}

public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ObjectPool<TItem> _pool;
    public TItem Item { get; set; }

    public Disposable(ObjectPool<TItem> pool, TItem item)
    {
        Item = item;
        _pool = pool;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _pool.Push(Item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A Pool is a good solution. After all, a pool is used for that purpose exactly (maintain a set of objects that are too expensive to instantiate every time: database connection, threads, etc..)

If you want to build a *generic* pool, however, you have to be very careful: users of your code may do "unexpected" things, and end up shooting themselves on the foot.

Locking, for example: you should really check that this does not lead to deadlock. Enlarging the pool on-the-fly, if needed, or throwing if the delegate asks for more objects...
Exceptions should be treated carefully too.

Therefore, the "wait for the first available T" and "lock the T" steps should be completely handled by the pool, and it should do all the necessary checks to avoid awkward situations. You can think about providing your "client code" (the target) with a reference to the pool to require additional lock abilities, if you want to (e.g. nested locking or something like that)

More practically: you could start with a solution that works specifically for your `Analyser` class, and then work from there towards a generic pool when you need it?